# Can I use Flask and flask-restul to return JSON to API calls but HTML to browsers?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm building a webapp for a personal project and I'd like to be able to serve JSON to api calls and HTML to websites.

My code is pretty similar to this:

```
class TestAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
    def post(self):
        data = request.form["data"]            
        result = do_something(data)
        return {'result': result}

@mod.route("/")
def test():
    return render_template("test.html")

@mod.route("/do_something", methods=['GET','POST'])
def analyzer():
    form = TestForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.get("data")
        result = do_something(data)
        return render_template("result.html", result=result)
    return render_template("do_something.html", form=form)
```

I was hoping this would let a user navigate to the page and submit data in a form, have the data manipulated, and returned in another html page (using jinja templates). I was hoping it would also let a user curl the endpoints to do the same thing, except just getting JSON values back.

It seems like what happens depends on the order in which I define things:

```
from app.views.test import test

api.add_resource(TestAPI, '/do_something')
```

When it's set up like this, I get HTML from everything (in browsers and even from curl). If I reverse it, I get JSON everywhere. Is there a way for me to get both? (HTML in browser, JSON otherwise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say in your backend, check the `'User-Agent'`parameter in the header of the request. If its a browser, return the html template.  If it is an API, return json.

## Edit

Credit to **Piotr Dawidiuk**

The above solution is not the most elegant way to do it. The `accept` attribute is more appropriate for determining json or html.

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media
> types which are acceptable for the response. Accept headers can be
> used to indicate that the request is specifically limited to a small
> set of desired types, as in the case of a request for an in-line
> image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! How do I check the user agent in flask? Would it come in as a header with the http request?

Comment: Oh I see you edited! Sounds like it is a header. Would you suggest not using flask-restful at all then and just determining which to return in each flask route?

Comment: @lnbl I am not particularly familiar with flask but I would just check the header in each flask route and code the logic accorddingly

Comment: @lnbl also , FYI you can open up chrome inspection and click on network to see chrome User-Agent, same rule applies to any browser if you want the information about which browser it is

Comment: Thanks @Bobby I'll give that a shot

Comment: @Bobby Hello buddy, it should be controlled with `Accept` header, that's why this header exists. Controlling it with `User-agent` is not clean and sounds like a workaround, please edit ur answer :)